# How to find an element using Selenium WebDriver, when Id is not contant (<input id="ext-gen26")

Tags: extjs, xpath, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I need help in finding an element using Selenium WebDriver. I have tried all the possible selectors, but I am unable to locate the element.

FYI. id="ext-gen26" is not constant, this will change every time when the new page is loaded.

```
Tried Selectors:

    By.xpath("//button[@class=\"x-btn-text\"]/text()='Find Accounts'")
    By.cssSelector(input[name='id'])
    By.id("ext-gen26") 

Code:
    <div id="x-form-el-ext-gen26" class="x-form-element" style="padding-left:155px">
    <input id="ext-gen26" class="x-form-text x-form-field " type="text" name="id" 
    autocomplete="off" size="20" style="width: 212px;">
    </div>
```

I want to locate Account ID element and send text to located element.

Appreciate if you can please shed some lights.

Comment: You need to explain lite more detailed what a the rule to access this element. For example the xpath to select this input with xpath by class content would be `//input[@class='x-form-text x-form-field ']`

Answer (score 0):

Does the div's id change everytime you load a new page too ?

I suggest to you to write something like that :

css Selector : `"div.x-form-element input"`

But, if you have a lot of div with `x-form-element` as `class` value, you can use the `nth-child()` function. like :

css Selector : `"div.x-form-element:nth-child(n) input" // n is the position order of your div that has x-form-element as class value.`

[nth-child() documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach: use ExtJS component query on client side to get the ID, then use the ID to locate WebElement. To send keys, you usually need to dig one level deeper to get the "inputEl". Java Code sample:

```
//a fully qualified ExtJS component query that will return one match only
String query = "viewport #panel1 textfield[fieldLabel='Test Field']";
//use component query to find id
String js = "return Ext.ComponentQuery.query(\"" + query + "\")[0].inputEl.id;";
String id = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) _driver).executeScript(js);    
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
element.sendKeys("it works");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application under test must be having labels behind input fields, combo boxes, check boxes etc.

Please try something like below, considering you application is having label as "Account ID"

```
(//*[text()='Account ID']/following::input)[1]
```

HTML code will looks like this-

```
<html>
<div id="x-form-el-ext-gen26" class="x-form-element" style="padding-left:155px">
    <label>Account ID: </label>
    <input id="ext-gen26" class="x-form-text x-form-field " type="text" name="id" 
    autocomplete="off" size="20" style="width: 212px;">
    </div>
</html>
```

This kind of xpath will never fail unless there is change in label.